# ¿Cómo hacer que cada vez que se muestre variable se sume +1 php?

Tags: php

Buenas como puedo hacer que cada vez que la variable se muestre se aumente en 1 ejemplo:

```
<?php 
$variable = "Imagen";
?>

<html>
<body>

<?php echo $variable ?>  = Imagen1  
<?php echo $variable ?>  = Imagen2
<?php echo $variable ?>  = Imagen3
<?php echo $variable ?>  = Imagen4

</body>
```

La cuestión es que la misma variable se sume por si sola cada vez que se muestra.

Comment: Un `for` simple `$variable = "Imagen"; for ($i=1; $i < 6; $i++) {  echo $variable.$i . "<br>"; }` , vamos ¡ Es programación básica ! .

Comment: @Dev.Joel es una respuesta mejor estructurada que las otras (en mi opinión), deberías publicarla, aunque creo que no son necesarias las comillas dobles en este caso ;)

Answer (score 2):

Puede utilizar el operador **++** Esto incrementa en uno el valor de la variable.

Si se antepone **++$variable** primero incrementa y luego retorna.

Sí se pospone **$variable++** primero retorna y luego incrementa.

Este mismo concepto vale para el operador de decremento **--**

Puedes encontrar más información en el manual

http://php.net/manual/es/language.operators.increment.php

Answer (score 0):

Suponiendo que no sean un bucle que puedas usar un loop como un `for` o un `while`.

```
<?php 
$variable = "Imagen";
$count = 1;
?>

<html>
<body>

<?php echo $variable.$count++ ?>   
<?php echo $variable.$count++ ?>
<?php echo $variable.$count++ ?>
<?php echo $variable.$count++ ?>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Con un For puedes imprimirlo sin problema.

```
   for($i =0; $i<=10; $i++){
    echo $variable . $i;
    }
```